# spring webflux why did controller subscribe on main thread

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Given this code:

```
  private static CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
  
  @GetMapping("/mono")
  public Mono<Object> testMono(@RequestBody Mono<SignInRequest> body) {
    countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Mono<Integer> objectMono = Mono.just(25);
    return objectMono
        .flatMap(i -> body.flatMap(b -> doWork(i)));
  }
  
  @GetMapping("/mono/2")
  public Mono<Object> testMono2(Integer a) {
    countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Mono<Integer> mono = Mono.just(99);
    Mono<Integer> objectMono = Mono.just(a);
    return objectMono
        .flatMap(i -> mono.flatMap(b -> doWork(i)));
  }
  
  private Mono<Object> doWork(Integer i) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
      if(countDownLatch.await(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        return i;
      }
      throw new RuntimeException("time exceeded");
    });
  }
```

When I invoke endpoint `/mono` it print `reactor-http-nio-3` (main thread), but when I invoke endpoint `/mono2` it print `parallel-2`. Why is there a difference? AFAIK, spring should always subscribe on parallel/elastic thread.

EDIT:

Please get the example [here](https://github.com/anaconda875/reacrive-bug.git)

How to run: You will need a mongodb instance which is running on 27017 and having a database named `vilya_be` (please correct username, password if any); also need a kafka instance running on 9092

Why didn't I remove mongodb and kafka? Because I already did it, but then bot APIs giving me `parallel-2`. So I put them back

Comment: Don't know about the threads, but why are you creating new CountdownLatch instances in the methods?

Comment: You are logging at “execution” phase. If you want to understand subscription, add log to `.doOnSubscribe`

Comment: @SoT I've checked your code and got `parallel-*` in both cases. Could you provide more details (at least versions) or a better - link to the GitHub example? p.s. I'd recommend you put a breakpoint in the place where you write the log and try to find in the stack where the `publishOn` or `subscribeOn` operators are used. It looks like the request body mono has `publishOn` applied under the hood or something like that.

Comment: @YevheniiSemenov i will create a github example soon

Comment: @YevheniiSemenov I have created a example on GitHub. Kindly check my edit

Comment: @SoT posted my investigation as a separate answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reviewing the project you shared on your GitHub, I have identified the cause of such behavior. To provide a comprehensive response, I will divide it into two parts:

1. Why `parallel-*` threads are used by default in your app.
2. Why are you seeing `reactor-http-nio-*` in one specific endpoint.

---

### Why `parallel-*` threads are used by default in your app.

Spring WebFlux uses Netty under the hood by default. So, actually, it processes all incoming HTTP requests on `reactor-http-nio-*` threads. You can verify it by putting a breakpoint in the `onStateChange` method in class `HttpServer` that is located in `reactor-netty-http`.

[image]

So why do you see `parallel-*` threads? This is because the thread is changed later during a request processing. One of the `WebFilter`s, applied to your request is `ServerRequestCacheWebFilter`. According to documentation it:

> Configures the request cache which is used when a flow is interrupted (i.e. due to requesting credentials) so that the request can be replayed after authentication.

As part of this filter logic, the following code is executed:

[image]

And the following code as part of `removeMatchingRequest`:
[image]

Method `getSession` returns `Mono`; But we are interested in how this mono is created here. And it is the place we are looking for:

[image]

This is the place where the thread is switched from `reactor-http-nio-*` to `parallel-*`.

You can verify this by adding `.requestCache().disable()` to your `SecurityWebFilterChain` config. After this, all execution will be on `reactor-http-nio-*` threads.

Here you can find more details about why it work in such a way:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26958#issuecomment-856986682

### Why are you seeing `reactor-http-nio-*` in one specific endpoint.

Actually, the endpoint `@GetMapping("/mono")` is also executed on `parallel-*` thread. You can verify it by putting the log message at the first line of the handler method.

The `reactor-http-nio-*` thread comes with the request body `Mono<SignInRequest> body`. When you add this mono to your chain here: `objectMono.flatMap(i -> body.flatMap(b -> doWork(i)));`, thread switched to the `reactor-http-nio-*`. It works that way whenever you add a `@RequestBody` argument with a `Mono` type to any endpoint.

The reason for such behavior is partially explained in the first part. WebFlux uses Netty under the hood, and reading request body is another I/O operation that should be handled by `reactor-http-nio-*` threads.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. Btw if you think my post is useful, kindly to up vote it =))

Answer (score -2):

the difference is, By default, the data production process starts on the Thread that initiated the subscription meaning first method `testMono(@RequestBody Mono<SignInRequest> body) { ...}` has publisher as the parameter, which is the source of subscription initiated from and thus data production process started there, on the other side for method `testMono2(Integer a)` you do not subscribe manually in your method but rather passing it to the endpoint to response, which means webflux will handle data production process and subscription, and by default, webflux uses `Schedulers.parallel()` to use parallel threads for project reactor. hope this helps

Comment: But i did not invoke subscribe at both methods

Comment: non of them require to be invoked manually by you, and this is the point, it first mono is invoked in request by HTTP request from endpoint, second mono is invoked by webflux upon responding

Comment: I still cannot understand completely, could you help to provide an example with code snippet?